# How to add gradle plugin in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

While trying to add tabs in a single page in android. I searched it on internet and got various ways to do that but i am not able to add `build.gradle` dependencies in my project. I am coding in **Eclipse v22.3.0-887826**. I am not able to add gradle plugin please guide me for the same.

Comment: Just a friendly note: you should instead move on to `AndroidStudio`.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong.I am new in android.For adding tabs in a single screen in android first i have to include some build.gradle dependencies which i am not able to do..

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use eclipse? Try [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzLTGjNKf1gIV0hdoCh1pCQL1EAAYASAAEgJe0fD_BwE)

Comment: **The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported** Use android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you move on to Android Studio because it is official IDE for Android development.
But if you want to use Eclipse for any specific reason then follow the instruction from below link: 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html

Providing link from Vogella for more details and photo guide for setup.